# How Laravel dynamic array columns name for where like query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

How Laravel dynamic array columns name for where like query?

**Sample:**

```
User::where(['name', 'surname'], 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%')->get();
```

**But error :**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `deneme` where (`0` = name and `1` = surname) and `user`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Comment: You cannot use 2 columns with same like . Try `User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $value . '%')
     ->orWhere('surname', 'like', '%' . $value . '%')`

Comment: @TheNobleBrain now your array has name, surname, does it contain more attributes ? or can array can be null?

Comment: @TheNobleBrain you want "where" or  "or where"?

Comment: Domain names come dynamically in array type. Now it sounds static. I must dynamically generate the query based on the dynamically arriving array.

Comment: @TheNobleBrain You can iterate the loop through the column array. Try my answer.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try this:

```
$field = ['name', 'surname'];
$name = User::Where(function ($query) use($field, $value) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($field); $i++){
                $query->orwhere($field[$i], 'like',  '%' . $value .'%');
            }      
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically create you query using  `LIKE clause` as below:

```
$query = User::query();
$count = 0;

foreach($conditions as $column) {

 if(count == 0){ 
    $query = $query->where($column, 'like', '%' . $value . '%') 
 } else {
    $query = $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%' . $value . '%') }
 }

  $count++


}

$user = $query->get();
```

Comment: $query = User::query();
            $conditions = ['name', 'surname'];
            foreach ($conditions as $column) {
                $query = $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            }
            $data = $query->orderByDESC('id')->paginate(10);